# Percentage sign in MySql

Tags: mysql

Does it also match empty string, or only non-empty strings? I have been trying to find a reference unsuccesfully.

Comment: [See here for reference](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_The_LIKE_Operator.htm)

Comment: Buzz - that's a shitty answer. Its too bad I can't downvote it. Perhaps you should try something like `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root';` and `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';` and see what you get back from a typical MySQL installation. I can tell you for certain `%` does not match `root@localhost`, `root@::1`, `root@127.0.0.1`, etc. All I could get is `ERROR 1141`. (Its the reason I'm here on this question).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you try it yourself and see? At any rate, here are the docs you were looking for:

> With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern.
>
> | Character | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | % | Matches any number of characters, even zero characters |
> | _ | Matches exactly one character |

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 6):

Such an old question w/o answer, but apparently in a context of creating a procedure % stands for any hosts.

i.e.:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `*internalProcedureName*`
```

- % wildcard for the HOST stands for **any hosts**

Ref.:

- [MySQL 8.0 Create Procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) - while it does not clarify % itself but procedure only

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the following demo to explain

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90ae1/2)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Val VARCHAR(50),
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
INSERT INTO Table1 (Val) SELECT 'TEST';
INSERT INTO Table1 (Val) SELECT '';

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Val LIKE '%'
```

Also from [12.5.1. String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

```
% Matches any number of characters, even zero characters
```